# Invalid token generating from service-principal and secret based login method

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

1. Configured service principal and trying to use the token received from the method to hit customer insights API.

[https://api.ci.ai.dynamics.com/v1/instances/{instanceId}/profilestore/stateinfo](https://api.ci.ai.dynamics.com/v1/instances/%7BinstanceId%7D/profilestore/stateinfo)

Above API requires bearer token as header for authorization.

Token receiving from auth response is invalid and not accepting by Customer Insights API.

```
msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(clientId, secret, 
tenantId).then((authres) => {
console.dir(authres, { depth: null })
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
```

[image]

2. Also, tried the another method of getting access token using this endpoint
   Still the token we are receiving are not getting accepted by customer insights.

   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'tenantid'/oauth2/v2.0/token';

Comment: The `resource` in the response indicates the token is for Azure's ARM API. Can you somehow specify the resource/scope to that library? It needs to match the API you are trying to call. You could also try using MSAL.js instead of that library.

Comment: if we give scope in azure app registration, it is not working and not able to send scope parameter in library. is there any approach or sample to specify the resource/scope. i am new to the azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-insights/audience-insights/apis

If you request the token with [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), it's need to add the **application permission**.

[image]

You could test [in Postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) using the scope(resource) `https://azurecustomerinsights.com/`.

```
POST https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={}
&resource=https://azurecustomerinsights.com/
&client_secret={}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

**Server to Server via Client Credentials, see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node):**

```
var adal = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var clientId = 'yourClientIdHere';
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'
var resource = 'https://azurecustomerinsights.com/';

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have installed the adal-node npm package. post this getting the below error.


'var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);
              ^

ReferenceError: AuthenticationContext is not defined'

Comment: You need to add `var AuthenticationContext = adal.AuthenticationContext;` first, refer to the whole [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/client-credentials-sample.js).

Comment: got this following error
Error: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://azurecustomerinsights.com/CustomerInsights.Api.All was not found in the tenant named <tenantid>. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. 

But have given grant permission to that resource in my app registration

Comment: Have you granted admin consent for your tenant? Plz read the article again. And try to change resource with `https://azurecustomerinsights.com/`.

Comment: yes granted access to tenant. kept const tenant ="tenantvalue.onmicrosoft.com". tested using this as well. const tenant ="tenantvalue"

Comment: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant 'tenantid.onmicrosoft.com' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.

this what i am facing

Comment: Make sure you have the correct `tenant ID`, looks like `var tenant = 'xxxxxxxx-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb';`

Comment: have given the tenant id correctly. still the issue exists. not working

Comment: Could you test with Postman? And we need more details about your issue. The error(AADSTS90002) is related to tenant, the tenant is always `{your tenant name}.onmicrosoft.com` or `GUID from Application -> Overview -> Directory ID`.

Comment: in postman it is always saying as grant_type is not available even it is already provided. have given the clientid, and other details in form-data in postman

Comment: My test with graph(because I have no subscription for Customer Insights): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuPKp.png

Comment: No it is not working i have used direct token endpoint to get access token